# Nginx remote access log

Tags: nginx, logstash, logstash-forwarder

Actually, I have **Nginx** and **Logstash** installed on the same machine.
And I want to separate them. I've installed **Logstash** in an other machine.

How can I store the `accsess_log` **Nginx** file in the second machine ?

Or

How can I set the a **Logstash** remote input file ?

Should I user an other tool like **logsatsh-forwarder** ?

Best regards,
Nizar.

Comment: This question is too board, you can save your log file to NAS, network share or even rsync to a folder of logstash server...

Comment: Thank you, can you explain with more details please ?

Comment: Read docs on access_log